Getting fetch error using gql.tada with Bun
I am trying to use gql.tada with VSCode and Bun and... the duck ain’t quacking.
I followed the instructions closely, including adding the following to tsconfig.json:
   "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "@0no-co/graphqlsp",
        "schema": "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
        "tadaOutputLocation": "./server/graphql-env.d.ts"
      }
    ]

and nothing.  It is supposed to generate a file called graphql-env.d.ts and it decided not to.  No error, warning, or complaint.
I tried bunx gql.tada doctor, and it responded:
✔ Checking TypeScript version
✔ Checking installed dependencies
✔ Checking tsconfig.json
✔ Checking VSCode setup
✘ Checking schema
 ⚠ Unexpected Error
Failed to load schema.
┗ CombinedError: [Network] fetch is not defined

It might be that “doctor” just doesn’t work with bun — but shouldn’t the generation run directly in VSCode and not have that problem?  If I could see that the generation were failing, with some sort of message, at least that would be something.
